# python scipy.optimize.newton says it does not converge, however it seems as it would

Tags: python, scipy

I am using python with scipy for writing some code to converge Cartesian coordinates to Kepler elements and the other way round.

For converting Cartesian to Kepler I use the following expression:

```
E = scopt.newton(self.f, self.M, self.df, args=(), tol=10^(-10), maxiter=10000)
```

with

```
self.f = lambda x: x-self.e*scipy.sin(x)-self.M
self.df= lambda x: 1-self.e*scipy.cos(x)
```

When running the entire code I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to converge after 10000 iterations, value is 5.25182613825
```

If I run it for less iterations (50), I get:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to converge after 50 iterations, value is 5.25182613825
```

Comparing the two values it obviously converges. Even if I reduce the tolerance to 10^(-2) i still get the same runtime error.

Does anybody knows why this error occurs?

Comment: If you run it 51 iterations, do you get the same value? Or is it flipping two values?

Comment: RuntimeError: Failed to converge after 51 iterations, value is 5.25182613825 So it's the same value...

Comment: Is 5.25182613825 a correct solution? What are the values of self.e and self.M?

Comment: it looks like 5.25182613825 is a correct solution. At least the results I get by just setting E=5.25182613825 seem to be ok. M =301.149932402*(math.pi/180) and e =0.004932091570 ( mean anomaly and eccentricity)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The exponentiation operator in Python is `**`. Use `tol=10**(-10)` or `1E-10`.

`^` is bitwise XOR.